# The need your game fills. Establishing your "hook."

Tags: game-design

I am a programmer and have worked on games although never attempted design myself. I am now attempting to design a game myself, working with a modest team of programmers and artists.

Game designers have been telling me it is important to establish the need your game fills, in order to develop a more complete vision of the product. I think in terms of mechanics and gameplay and am having trouble finding a "hook," even in existing games.

Any advice in identifying why a mechanic is fun, and what need a game fills, to help develop my own ideas is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean finding a niche?

Comment: Not so much a niche, more like the selling point. I apologize if I am being vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought this [article on prototyping games in under 7 days](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2438/how_to_prototype_a_game_in_under_7_.php) had some interesting ideas. The suggested focusing on a single theme and exploring it:

> “gravity”, “springs”, “evolution”, “sound”, “predator and prey”, “addictive games”, “drawing”, “exponential growth”, “vegetation”, “balance”.

I also appreciated the suggestion to focus on getting it working quickly so you can get a feel for the mechanics and if it's not right, fail quickly and move on to the next idea.

Comment: Great article, with some very good suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Find your OWN need that wants to be filled. My personal game idea is something that I've searched high and low for, but I've not been able to find a great game to fill that void.

Because I also have fairly typical interests, I get encouraged by the fact that my game will likely not fail. That it's something I really really want to play helps me keep motivated too.

Minecraft (seems to by my favorite example these days) was built because Notch noticed a void that needed to be filled. He filled it and is now a multimillionaire.

Find something missing and build that. It's the best reason for building a game ever. =)

Answer (score 3):

On identifying why a game is fun, [A Theory of Fun](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932111972) is a good book.

Comment: +1 This looks like it will be a tremendous resource for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I get most of my motivation, inspiration, and design ideas from playing other games. In fact, most of my motivating "spark" comes straight from the super nintendo emulator these days.

Comment: This is good advice. As is, I already play a slew of games both new and retro of many different genres. That is probably what makes not being able to identify what need these games fill so  disappointing.

Comment: Play more games! Even if you don't want to invest in the platform / game itself, watch some videos on youtube. I develop mobile games, so I'm always looking through the latest games that are released, and I've found some great ideas in doing so.

Comment: I primarily deal in mobile myself although not games. A lot of the mechanics in hit mobile games are lifted directly from retro games so I try to analyze them when I play. Given this is a PC game and my first crack at design, its a bit exciting given opportunities the hardware offers, but daunting given the high bar and amazing content a lot of independent studios are creating,

Answer (score 0):

You might pick a pick you like, and figure out how you could improve it. Or take a game that you thought had potential but didn't deliver, and figure out what could have saved it. In the process, you may come up with an idea that you like.